# Electronic Reset SW

Tags: switches, reset

Normally, there is a mechanic button at the end of the RESET SW pins on the mainboard. Now, I like to create a way to electronically trigger the reset function of my mainboard from another computer. What is the most simple way to do this? I have no knowledge about electronics but I have programming skills, e.g., I could code something for Arduino. That is, I'm only interested in the electronics layer. Would it be possible to do this via a transistor or is there another element which is mores suitable for this purpose (e.g., relay?)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with electronics, I would hook up a relay parallel to the regular reset button. There are really cheap relay brake out boards available.

Comment: I found this one http://www.1topstore.com/product_info.php?products_id=21149&language=en. The relay is specified for controlling high currents, will this also work for controlling low currents as in my situation?

Comment: Sure, will do perfectly well for your project, no extra transistors required and the relay only draws 50mA each, so it can be fed from USB. I have exact same module lying next to my keyboard. It looks just fine, but I am unsure if it is wise to switch mains power with them. But that is not your intension anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use a relay.  The normally open contact of the relay is wired accross (in parallel with) the existing pushbutton.  When the relay is engergized, it will be indistiguishable to the mainboard from the pushbutton pressed.  Since the relay provides isolation, you don't have to worry about ground loops, ground offsets, and the like.

There surely must be lots out there on how to drive a relay from a digital output.  This can easily be done with a NPN transistor, a base resistor, and a diode accross the relay coil.  If you can't find this after a little looking around, let me know and I can get into more detail.  I'm pretty sure I've answered that question several times here alone, but it's often difficult to find previous answers.

### Added:

I found one place where I answered how to drive a relay from a digital output [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/51746/4512).  In this example the power supply happened to be 12V.  It can be any value as long as it matches what the relay wants to turn on.  Relays are available in a variety of coil voltages, like 5V, 12V, 24V, and many others.  If you have a 5V or 12V supply it will be easy to find a small relay to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the reset button on your computer, it is normally a simple normal-open push button.

To trigger it from a microcontroller, you can use a simple mechanical relay or a transistor or a mosfet. If you want better isolation, a optocoupler. All of these can be triggered by a digital pin write on a arduino.

Comment: A relay is already isolated, so the opto-coupler addition only applies to the direct transistor approach.  You make it sound like it might be needed with the relay too, which it isn't.