# Convert 2.9V to 5V to operate relay using limited resources

Tags: voltage, transistors, voltage-regulator, boost

I brought a relay *module* which works when 5V are given to its input pin to switch on high voltage.

But my raspberry pi GPIO pins give out only 2.9V (measured from multimeter, it was supposed to give 3.3V).

I have only below mentioned things available in my locality :-
BC-557 (PNP), BC-548b (NPN), LM-317t (Voltage Regulator), some resistors.

How do I operate relay using above mentioned electronics components? Please keep the circuit simple BUT safe for my raspberry pi.

Comment: Looks like a homework.

Comment: Not its not, I have only those things... help me

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51744/how-to-control-4-relays-with-a-not-chip-7404

Comment: This question was marked as exact duplicate of a question related to NOT GATE (inverter) ! What's wrong with these people :(

Comment: Because the solution to that question will actually be the solution to this one?

Comment: So, what should I use instead of Q1 and D1 from answer to the linked question  (BC557 or BC548b)... also what resister value should i use instead of 540 Ohms ( for conversion from 2.9V to 5V)

Comment: @PankajKumar the schematic in that answer doesn't make you think about it?

Comment: To be fair, the answer to that question assumes that a 12V supply is available.

Comment: @Finbarr RapsberryPi board has 5V input voltage. And OP has 5V relay. It's not hard to figure out the rest. Or is it? Hm...

Comment: @Chupacabras so, i connect bc-548b in place of 2n4401... but what kind of diode is D1? i dont have any diode! and what resister value should i use instead of 540 ohms.... you talk like smart but not answering me...

Comment: @PankajKumar you MUST use a diode when you switch inductive load. A relay is inductive load. Otherwise you'll damage that transistor sooner or later.

Comment: @PankajKumar The value of resistor must chosen so the switching transistor will saturate. You do the math. Read datasheets, and google about transistors. There are MANY articles about transistors.